# How to stop processing if htaccess HTTP Auth fails

Tags: .htaccess, http-authentication

I am trying to use HTTP Authentication in a website root (`public_html`) that has `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`. When I visit the website, it gives me the prompt, but when I cancel, it prompts me again, several times. Then finally, it stops prompting and gives me the home page HTML with the linked resources i.e. images, JS, CSS etc. unavailable.

I have a feeling the HTTP Authentication failure did not cause the htaccess script to stop processing further, hence the RewriteRule still generated content. How can I tell htaccess to "stop processing further if auth failed"?

```
# manually added
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Added by cpanel password protect directory
AuthUserFile "/home/username/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Stage"
require valid-user

# Manually added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need an additional `RewriteCond` on your rewrite, to only proceed if you have a valid user. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```